# How to use directly query using mybatis?

Tags: spring, mariadb, mybatis

i want use this query 'ANALYZE TABLE {tableName}' but i think mybatis supports only CRUD.
how to use 'ANALYZE TABLE' in mybatis?

Comment: Have you tried? It should work as a normal SELECT.

Comment: nope. because normal SELECT needs a return type.

Answer (score 1):

Just declare it as a normal select and specify `Map` as the return type.

```java
@Select("analyze table ${tableName}")
Map<String, Object> analyzeTable(String tableName);
```

```java
@Test
public void testAnalyzeTable() {
  try (SqlSession sqlSession = sqlSessionFactory.openSession()) {
    Mapper mapper = sqlSession.getMapper(Mapper.class);
    Map<String, Object> result = mapper.analyzeTable("users");
    assertEquals("test.users", result.get("Table"));
    assertEquals("analyze", result.get("Op"));
    assertEquals("status", result.get("Msg_type"));
    assertEquals("OK", result.get("Msg_text"));
  }
}
```

Tested using...

- MariaDB 10.4.10
- MariaDB Connector/J 2.5.4